# How can I remove the error related to "base64-string" to download pdf using jsPDF in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, pdf, material-ui, jspdf

I have a button named "Download Payslip". When I click on it, payslip will be downloaded as pdf. All the calculations are done in client side by server provided json data. Calculation is in a separate react component which I need to download as pdf and the component is hidden by the css property "display: none" because this component is no need to show in UI, it is only for download.
But the fact is when I go to download the payslip it is showing this error ,

> applied data is not a valid base64-string jspdf.convertstringtoimagedata

if I remove the "display: none" from the component then the payslip is being downloaded properly.
How can I solve this problem?

here is the download function

```
const handlePdf = () => {
    let input = document.getElementById("content");
    html2canvas(input)
      .then((canvas) => {
        let imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        let pdf = new jsPDF('landscape', 'px', 'a4', 'false');
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0);
        pdf.save("download.pdf");
       
      })
    ;
}
```

here is the download button

```
      <IxButton
          onClick={handlePdf}
          variant="contained"
          fullWidth
          color="primary"
          className={classes.nxtBtnPrimary + ' ' + classes.btnPrint}
          disabled={!invoiceData}
        >
          {t('downloadPayslipButton')}
       </IxButton>
```

here is the payslip component which will be downloaded

```
     <div style={{display: 'none'}} id='content'>
          {invoiceData ? (
            <ComponentToPrint
              orderId={displayOrderNo}
              payResponse={invoiceData}
              ref={componentRef}
            />
          ) : null}
      </div>
```

Comment: I guess (but don't know) that you are getting the error because display: none will mean that element is not rendered. Could you try hiding it some other way - for example placing it a long way out of the viewport rather than display none?

Comment: yes, I also think that it is for "display: none" but what is alternative way? because I also need "display: none".

Comment: You can't have display none. Why will the suggestion that you put the element off screen not work?